# Slider - right left and bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna create this slider.
**https://www.interiorsbyreneej.com/**

My codes;

JS

```
$('#image').animate({right:'700x'},1200)
$('#image2').animate({left:'100px'},1200)
$('#image3').animate({top:'100px'},1200)
```

CSS

```
img{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img id="image" src="https://www.ceyye.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/maxresdefault-1000x600.jpg">
<img id="image2" src="https://www.ceyye.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/maxresdefault-1000x600.jpg">
<img id="image3" src="https://www.ceyye.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/maxresdefault-1000x600.jpg">
```

Cloud u please someone help? Im newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery.animate is resource-heavy and I wouldn't recommend you doing it unless you really (I mean REALLY) have no other option.

Instead, I'd recommend you a different approach: css-based animations (transitions in this case).

So the css would be something like this:

```
img {
position: absolute;
transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
opacity: 0;
}    

img.show {
opacity: 1;
transform: none;
}

.image1 {
left: 0;
top: 20px;
transform: translateX(50px);
}
.image2 {
left: 100px;
top: 20px;
transform: translateY(-50px);
}
.image3 {
left: 80px;
top: 0;
transform: translateX(-50px);
}
```

Note that initially each image has styles that position it in the final place (left and top properties) but each of them is translated (offset) a little. Also its opacity is set to 0 which makes them invisible.
The transition property tells us which properties will be animated and how long will the animation last.

Of course you can set any top, left and translate values to anything you find suitable.

I also recommend you the good practice of styling by classes, not IDs, which my example uses.

Now, we'll use the JS to add the 'show' class to each image to remove the offset and increase its opacity so the images will move and fade into position. So the JS can look like this (many other solutions are possible of course) - no jquery needed:

```
var i = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
// find the image in DOM
const img = document.querySelector('.image' + i);
//add the class
img.classList.add('show');
//increment the variable to pick another image
i++;
// clear interval when all images are done
if (i === 3) {
clearInterval(interval);
}
}, 1200);
```

Should work now :-)